# Does int.class equal Integer.class or Integer.TYPE in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, primitive-types, boxing

Let's imagine one retrieves the declaring type of a `Field` using reflection.

Which of the following tests will correctly indicate whether one is dealing with an `int` or an `Integer`?

```
Field f = ...
Class<?> c = f.getDeclaringClass();
boolean isInteger;

isInteger = c.equals(Integer.class);
isInteger = c.equals(Integer.TYPE);
isInteger = c.equals(int.class);

isInteger = ( c == Integer.class);
isInteger = ( c == Integer.TYPE);
isInteger = ( c == int.class);
```

Comment: The issue with testing myself only is that there is a risk of missing a corner case. That's why I am asking the question.

Comment: **JVersty** is correct. Implementation and specification are different things. He want to know about specification which are more to hard then just run a piece of code... +1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Based on `Field.getType()` (instead of `f.getDeclaringClass()`), I get the following:

```
Type: java.lang.Integer

equals(Integer.class): true
equals(int.class)    : false
equals(Integer.TYPE) : false
== (Integer.class)   : true
== (int.class)       : false
== (Integer.TYPE)    : false

Type: int

equals(Integer.class): false
equals(int.class)    : true
equals(Integer.TYPE) : true
== (Integer.class)   : false
== (int.class)       : true
== (Integer.TYPE)    : true

Type: java.lang.Object

equals(Integer.class): false
equals(int.class)    : false
equals(Integer.TYPE) : false
== (Integer.class)   : false
== (int.class)       : false
== (Integer.TYPE)    : false
```

Meaning the following is true:

```
Integer.TYPE.equals(int.class)
Integer.TYPE == int.class
```

Meaning if I want to find out whether I am dealing with an `int` or an `Integer`, I can use any of the following tests:

```
isInteger = c.equals(Integer.class) || c.equals(Integer.TYPE);
isInteger = c.equals(Integer.class) || c.equals(int.class);
isInteger = (c == Integer.class) || (c == Integer.TYPE);
isInteger = (c == Integer.class) || (c == int.class );
```

Is there a corner case I am missing? If yes, please comment.

Comment: And there are no corner cases missing, unless you count a field that is declared as `Object` and winds up storing an `Integer`

Comment: Oh yeah, and `Integer` extends `Number`, so there's another possible corner case if it matters.

Answer (score 24):

`int.class` compiles down to `Integer.TYPE`. However, I think you are using [`Field.getDeclaringClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) incorrectly, as this returns the `Class` object representing the class that declares the field. What you would want to use is [`Field.getType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that int.class points to Integer.TYPE

Comment: .class is a compile time construct. int.class gets compiled to a field access which loads Integer.TYPE.

Comment: @Antimony Interesting, I'd never looked at the bytecode. Edited and thanks.