# Java Class.isAssignableFrom confusion

Tags: java, reflection

I find primitive type problem

```
System.out.println("Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class) = " + Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class));
System.out.println("int.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class) = "+int.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class));
```

both of the statements return false to the caller. so that seems like boxing is not applicable here. My question is if my observation is correct or there are other API who can do this testing correctly?

--------------------------------following up---------------------------------------------

As I said, I mainly want to check if a Object is assignable to a Field when using reflection. I hope the mechanism could be more precise at run time so I made a implementation like this.

```
    public static boolean isAssignableFrom(final Field field, final Object obj) {


        if (field.getType().equals(Integer.class) || field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || field.getType().equals(int.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Float.class) || field.getType().equals(float.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Float.class) || field.getType().equals(float.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Double.class) || field.getType().equals(double.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Double.class) || field.getType().equals(double.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Character.class) || field.getType().equals(char.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Character.class) || field.getType().equals(char.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Long.class) || field.getType().equals(long.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Long.class) || field.getType().equals(long.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Short.class) || field.getType().equals(short.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Short.class) || field.getType().equals(short.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Boolean.class) || field.getType().equals(boolean.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Boolean.class) || field.getType().equals(boolean.class);
        } else if (field.getType().equals(Byte.class) || field.getType().equals(byte.class)) {
            return obj.getClass().equals(Byte.class) || field.getType().equals(byte.class);
        }
        return field.getType().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass());
    }

}
```

That seems the best I can do -_-! thanks

Comment: Isn't autoboxing is accomplished at compile time?

Comment: I am not sure, I mean statement Integer a = 1 is compilable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does int.class equal Integer.class or Integer.TYPE in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082997/does-int-class-equal-integer-class-or-integer-type-in-java)

Comment: @Korben - autoboxing is a compile time process that boxes or unboxes *instances*. It doesn't apply to classes at all, which is what the `isAssignableFrom` method operates on. Key thing to keep in mind is - instances can be autoboxed, classes cannot.

Comment: @Perception Thanks for your clear explanation, is there anyway I can do this checking at runtime?

Comment: @Korben - I'm unsure as to what you are trying to test. Are you trying to verify that autoboxing is available in the version of Java you are using? Or something else?

Comment: @Perception I am trying to using reflection assign values to the Object fields, but I want to firstly verify if type matches, I find problem in int Integer, and Generic Typed field. I am not sure if isAssignableFrom is the only native support for this type of task or I missed some other accessories. thanks

Answer (score 11):

I suppose, `ClassUtils.isAssignable(Class, Class, boolean)` from Apache commons-lang is the one to help.

[JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#isAssignable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29)

Comment: The Apache method will work but will also allow for long is assignable from int to be true as well. You could just attempt to cast the object to the type yourself and then catch the classcastexception if it fails.

Answer (score 6):

`int.class` and `Integer.class` are two separate class objects. check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082997/does-int-class-equal-integer-class-or-integer-type-in-java) answer for more details

From Java doc [`Class#isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. **If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.**

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) on `isAssignableFrom`:

> this method tests whether the type represented by the specified Class parameter can be converted to the type represented by this Class object via an identity conversion or via a widening reference conversion. See The Java Language Specification, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.

`Integer` cannot be assigned to an `int` (or vice versa) through this way, so your method will return false - boxing and unboxing are done at compile time, not at runtime - see [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more info on it

Comment: but final Integer a = 1; final int b = new Integer(2); are OK

Comment: This is allowed only as a convenience - the compiler will basically turn that into `final Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1);` and `final int b = new Integer(2).intValue()` (there may be some optimization in there, but that's the gist of how autoboxing works).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, the code you pasted above has a bug in it.
If you call the method with "field= int.class", it does not matter what type object is, the method will always return true. Seems to be a copy and paster misstake ;)

```
if (field.getType().equals(Integer.class) || field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
        return obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || field.getType().equals(int.class);
```

better would be:

```
if (field.getType().equals(Integer.class) || field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
        return obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || obj.getType().equals(int.class);
```