# How to get Class of primitive types from Java JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This question is related to this question and its answer:

[Does int.class equal Integer.class or Integer.TYPE in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082997/does-int-class-equal-integer-class-or-integer-type-in-java)

Since int.class is not equal to Integer.class how can I get int.class Class or others primitive types at the native level through JNI ? I need the jclass object that point to int.class not Integer.class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This test

```
    System.out.println(Integer.TYPE == int.class);
```

prints `true`. That is, Integer.TYPE is what you want, you can read Integer.TYPE field from native code. Or call `Class.getPrimitiveClass("int")` from native code

Comment: Seem promising. I will try and let you know

Comment: Indeed reading the static field of Integer.TYPE at the native level provides the requested behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In JNI, the primitive values get passed as actual machine values.  An int is passed as a jint which is typedef'd to a 32-bit signed integer.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp9502

Comment: I already know this. Please reread my question. This is not the question I asked! I need the jclass of int.class. At the java level I would do:  Class objectClass = int.class.