# Calling the proper wrapper

Tags: java, wrapper

I'm making a programm which allow you to instanciate a class with a window. So there are fields, and when I want to convert in the good type I do like this :

```
if (f.getType() == int.class)
                           m.invoke(res, Integer.parseInt(f.getText()));

                    else if (f.getType() == double.class)
                        m.invoke(res, Double.parseDouble(f.getText()));
                    else if (f.getType() == boolean.class)
                        m.invoke(res, Boolean.parseBoolean(f.getText()));
 ....
```

Is there a way to do it with only one line? I've got to check every primitive type otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7082997/1120492

Comment: @Eko wants to ask "So there is no way to do it with only one line? I've got to check every primitive type?" +1 for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Class TYPE representing the primitive type
Each Primitive Wrapper classes contains static TYPE static field

for e.g. Integer class contais

```
public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");
```

Try this code:

```
     if (f.getType() == Integer.TYPE)
            m.invoke(res, Integer.parseInt(f.getText()));
     else if (f.getType() == Double.TYPE)
         m.invoke(res, Double.parseDouble(f.getText()));
     else if (f.getType() == Boolean.TYPE)
         m.invoke(res, Boolean.parseBoolean(f.getText()));
     ...
```

---

Or you can use `name()` method of TYPE class

Try this code:

```
     if (f.getType().getName().equals(int.class.getName()))
            m.invoke(res, Integer.parseInt(f.getText()));
     else if (f.getType().getName().equals(double.class.getName()))
         m.invoke(res, Double.parseDouble(f.getText()));
     else if (f.getType().getName().equals(boolean.class.getName()))
         m.invoke(res, Boolean.parseBoolean(f.getText()));
    ....
```

---

Or **use this code to do it in single line**

```
convert(f.getType(),f.getText());


import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorManager;

private Object convert(Class<?> targetType, String text) {
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType);
    editor.setAsText(text);
    return editor.getValue();
}
```

Comment: You should expand your answer to include an explanation.

Comment: So there is no way to do it with only one line? I've got to check every primitive type?

Comment: I have updated my code. Use `PropertyEditor` class. Please try it. Update you Question as you asked "So there is no way to do it with only one line? I've got to check every primitive type" to make it not duplicate question.

Comment: Perfect, it works fine, except for Strings and Characters. But for every other primitiv type it works