# Java - getting variable type for primitive data types

Tags: java, reflection, primitive

Is it possible to get the data type of an input variable (could be any primitive type, int, bool, float, double) returned as a string by using just one line of code? I know this can easily be done for a String type using `getName` and `getShortName` but I am unsure of how to use these methods to return the type of a primitive type. I also want to keep my code very short for doing this preferably using just one line.

I have searched around and cannot find anywhere this question has been answered in the way I require.

Comment: What do you mean by "an input variable"? It would really help if you could post a complete example of what you're trying to achieve, with an appropriate `magicMethod` call or whatever to represent the bit you don't know how to do.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but wouldn't you always know this at compile time anyway?  Since a primitive isn't an object there's no ambiguity, it must be whatever the declared type is?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this but you can not do this for primitive types. If possible you can use corresponding wrapper types.

Comment: Maybe this answer on SO to a similar topic [does-int-class-equal-integer-class-or-integer-type-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082997/does-int-class-equal-integer-class-or-integer-type-in-java#7083456) does help.

Answer (score 1):

What about `Class.getName()`?

> Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class,
>   primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a
>   String. If this class object represents a reference type that is not
>   an array type then the binary name of the class is returned, as
>   specified by the Java Language Specification, Second Edition.
>
> **If this class object represents a primitive type or void, then the
>   name returned is a String equal to the Java language keyword
>   corresponding to the primitive type or void**.

You can follow [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) in the Java Doc that explain very well how to use this method.